# ListView between LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, user-interface, android-fragments

I would like to have a ListView between two other layouts, but I haven't found any examples... I can make a ListView within a ListActivity, but it does not help me for what I am trying to acheive

//main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout vertical>

            <LinearLayout horizontal>
                <Spinners and Buttons here>
            </LinearLayout>

            **<LISTVIEW HERE">**

            <LinearLayout horizontal>
                <More Buttons etc>
            </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How would that make my main activity look? (Currently it just setContentView(main_layout) etc..) Do I need to create another class and subclass the listfragment? How?

Thanks for your help

Comment: add your linear layout as header and footer to listview.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know, the header will only display before I scroll down the list, and the footer will only display once I have reached the bottom of the list. I would like them to display constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would that make my main activity look?

Replace `**<I WANT A LISTVIEW HERE>**` with `<ListView>` with appropriate attributes. Specifically, if you want the `ListView` to fill all space not used by your two horizontal `LinearLayouts`, give the `ListView` an `android:layout_height="0dp"` and an `android:layout_weight="1"`. This tells Android to allocate all leftover room to the `ListView`.

> Currently it just setContentView(main_layout) etc.

That should not need to change. If your activity is a `ListActivity`, be sure to give your `ListView` an `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

> Do I need to create another class and subclass the listfragment?

Not necessarily. You are welcome to use a `ListFragment` instead of a `ListView` if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I find that if my MainActivity extends ListActivity, then my app crashes when I .setContentView()

I can't find any resources showing me how to use ListFragment in this case

Comment: @Captain-RayneMartin: " I find that if my MainActivity extends ListActivity, then my app crashes when I .setContentView()" -- make sure your `android:id` is set as I note in my answer. Beyond that, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. "I can't find any resources showing me how to use ListFragment in this case" -- until you take the time to learn what your real problem is, all this will do is waste time, as you may well have the same problem with a `ListFragment`. Read the stack trace.